# How to empty input box values with FORM VALIDATION in code-igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using form_validation library to validate my form .

Everything is working fine but after success-full case it is showing me all the values i filled. I am using ci v3. I don't want to do some redirection.

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == True){
        //saving values to db 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('registration_success', '<h4 class="alert alert-success">Registration successful.. Please check your email.</h4>');
         $this->_field_data = array();
        //$this->auth();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354490/codeigniter-resetting-the-form-values

check this...

Comment: **without redirect you want able to get flashdata**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After successful validation you can refresh the page so that old values don't show up doing something like this :

```
public function yourSaveFunction(){
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == True){
            //saving values to db 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('registration_success', '<h4 class="alert alert-success">Registration successful.. Please check your email.</h4>');
             $this->_field_data = array();
            //$this->auth();
             redirect('{your_current_controller_name/your_page_load_view}');
        }
}
```